# Query performance difference

Tags: mysql, performance, caching

1. `select * from table t inner join table_3 t3 on (t3.t_id=t.id) where t3.k_id IN(2,3,5);`
2. `select * from table t inner join table_3 t3 on (t3.t_id=t.id) where t3.k_id IN(select id from table_2);`

How do these two statements differ as performance in big tables? In 2nd statement, is the inner "select" queried again and again or is it queried once only? Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't make much difference. What does explain say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, these two queries are quite different. Compare the two query execution plans with [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html), it'll show a  `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY` select type for the second query. You can however [optimize your query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html) easily turning the dependent subquery intto a static subquery. It'll be something like

```
select *
from table t
inner join table_3 t3 on (t3.t_id=t.id)
where exists (select 1 from table2 where t3.k_id = table2.id);
```

Didn't try this out so please verify that both queries are equivalent.